# redirect print output into a csv file problem?

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

my problem is that i want to redirect my print into a csv file, i tried soemthing with the csv.writer but i get an error.

I want to get a csv file

I tried this:

```
rows = [
    ["La moyenne de frameRate est :",statistics.mean(numberList),"FPS"]
    ["Le frame rate max est:",max(numberList),"FPS"]
    ["Le FrameRate minimum est:",min(numberList),"FPS"]
    ["L'ecart type des FrameRate est:",statistics.stdev(numberList),"FPS"]
]
with open("C:\\Users\\skehal\\Desktop\\doc.csv",'wt') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in rows:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)

print("La moyenne de FrameRate est :" , statistics.mean(numberList),"FPS")
max(numberList)
print("Le frame rate max est:",max(numberList),"FPS")
min(numberList)
print("Le FrameRate minimum est:",min(numberList),"FPS")
print("L'ecart type des FrameRate est:",statistics.stdev(numberList),"FPS")

rows = [
    ["La moyenne de frameRate est :",statistics.mean(numberList),"FPS"]
    ["Le frame rate max est:",max(numberList),"FPS"]
    ["Le FrameRate minimum est:",min(numberList),"FPS"]
    ["L'ecart type des FrameRate est:",statistics.stdev(numberList),"FPS"]
]
with open("C:\\Users\\skehal\\Desktop\\doc.csv",'wt') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in rows:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

I get this error on my console :

```
["Le frame rate max est:",max(numberList),"FPS"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Add commas between rows. Otherwise `["La moyenne de frameRate est :",statistics.mean(numberList),"FPS"]
    ["Le frame rate max est:",max(numberList),"FPS"]` gets interpreted as indexing first list with second `[]`'s content

Comment: And that's literally the whole problem.

Comment: @h4z3 yeah i resolved it thank you my friend, end of day, exhausted error xD